# Any way to view and EC2 instance AlarmStatus value using AmazonEC2 API?

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I was wondering if there was a way to view an ec2 instance's alarm status through the AmazonEC2 API?

[image: AlarmStatus]

We've implemented a working solution to get specific metric values using the AmazonCloudWatch.GetMetricStatistics method:

```
var reg = new GetMetricStatisticsRequest()
            {
                MetricName = metric,
                Period = 60 * 30,
                Statistics = new List<string> { AVERAGE },
                Dimensions = dimensions,
                Namespace = "AWS/EC2",
                EndTime = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime(),
                StartTime = DateTime.Parse(startTime)
            };

data.Columns.Add(AVERAGE);
data.Columns.Add(TIMESTAMP);

var points = Service.GetMetricStatistics(reg).GetMetricStatisticsResult.Datapoints.OrderBy(p => p.Timestamp);
```

But it would be more useful to check the Alarm status directly.

We've iterated over the AmazonEC2.DescribeInstancesResponse result but no joy so far. Has anyone achieved this yet?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the status of the alarm you can use the AmazonCloudWatch.DescribeAlarms method.  Here is a code sample on how to get the alarm status (in the US-West-2 region):

```
        var cloudWatchClient = AWSClientFactory.CreateAmazonCloudWatchClient(RegionEndpoint.USWest2);
        var describeAlarmsResponse = cloudWatchClient.DescribeAlarms(new DescribeAlarmsRequest
        {
            AlarmNames = { "the_name_of_your_alarm" }
        });
        var describeAlarmsResult = describeAlarmsResponse.DescribeAlarmsResult;
        foreach (var alarm in describeAlarmsResult.MetricAlarms)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Alarm State = " + alarm.StateValue);
            Console.WriteLine("Alarm State Reason = " + alarm.StateReason);
            Console.WriteLine("Alarm JSON Data = " + alarm.StateReasonData);
        }
```

Comment: Link to the docs with a recent example: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CloudWatch/MCloudWatchDescribeAlarms.html